# Gnuplot: how to draw tangent line to curve at arbitrary point?

Tags: gnuplot, derivative

How to draw tangent line (of some length) to curve at arbitrary point? The curve if parametrically defined.

```
set samples 1000
dx0 = 2.
km = 0.3
omega = 2.
y0=1.
N = 3
set parametric
plot [0:N*2*pi/omega]     dx0*exp(-km*t)/(km**2 + omega**2) * (omega*sin(omega*t) - km*cos(omega*t))  ,     dx0*exp(-km*t)/(km**2 + omega**2) * (omega*cos(omega*t) + km*sin(omega*t))
```

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward way would be to take the derivative at the desired point and use it as slope for your straight line `g` definded by `gx(t)` and `gy(t)`.
Here you can take the approximate derivative from two points close to each other, let's say `t0` and `t0+dt` by choosing an appropriate `dt`.

However, what puzzles me, is that although in the plot command of `gx(t)` I specify `[t=-1:1] gx(t) ...` , gnuplot seems to again take the range `[0:N*2*pi/omega]`. Maybe there is a way to fix it which I haven't found yet.
So, that's why I define functions `hx(t)` and `hy(t)` for the negative direction.

**Edit:** thanks to @Ethan's comment on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58493814/7295599) the code can be simplified and `hx(t)` and `hy(t)` can be omitted:

**Code:**

```
### drawing a tangent to a parametric curve
reset session

set samples 1000
dx0 = 2.
km = 0.3
omega = 2.
y0=1.
N = 3
set parametric
set size square
set xrange[-0.8:1]
set yrange[-0.8:1]

fx(t) = dx0*exp(-km*t)/(km**2 + omega**2) * (omega*sin(omega*t) - km*cos(omega*t))
fy(t) = dx0*exp(-km*t)/(km**2 + omega**2) * (omega*cos(omega*t) + km*sin(omega*t))

t0 = 3.5
dt = 0.01
m = 100
gx(t) = fx(t0)+m*t*(fx(t0+dt)-fx(t0))
gy(t) = fy(t0)+m*t*(fy(t0+dt)-fy(t0))

plot [0:N*2*pi/omega] fx(t), fy(t) w l, \
     [-1:1] '+' u (gx($1)):(gy($1)) w l lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]