# gnuplot: how to set multiple ranges in parametric plots?

Tags: gnuplot

Can somebody explain why the second curve is not just the expected line from `0,0` to `1,1`, but a line from `0,0` to `2*pi,2*pi`? Why is the second range `[t=0:1]` ignored?
Bug or feature or did I miss anything in the manual?

**Code:**

```
### parametric curves
reset session

set parametric
set size square

plot [0:2*pi] cos(t), sin(t) w l, \
     [t=0:1] t, t w l
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Parametric mode is not relevant. gnuplot has never allowed axis range restrictions anywhere except the very start of a plot command. I advocate not placing them at the start either;  use a separate "set range" command.  You may be thinking of local sampling ranges introduced in version 5 to support pseudofiles '+' and '++'.  Those only affect the sampling range, not the axis range.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Ok, in the above case with '+' it will work if you use the `u 1:1` syntax. 
Then what is the difference between `plot cos(t),sin(t)` and `plot '+' u (cos($1)):(sin($1))`, except the first one is easier to write and read?
The follow-up question would be: is it possible to have different samplings, e.g. first curve 1000 samples, second curve 10 samples? So far, I guess you can `set samples` only before the plot command and it will hold for all curves, right?

Comment: Parametric mode is no longer needed, although as you say it can be easier to read. Yes you can have different sampling ranges and intervals. E.g.`splot '++' using 1:2:($1*25.*sin($2/10)),       [u=30:70:5][v=0:50:2] '++' using 1:2:(u*v)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of axis ranges at the start of a plot command is a historical artifact. It confuses the program as well as the user, and since the introduction of sampling ranges in version 5 it leads to potentially ambiguous syntax.   To disambiguate the syntax you can place the keyword `sample` in front of the range specifier for the first plot component:

```
set style data linespoints
set key left
plot sample [14:22:2] '+' u 1:1 pt "1" ti "sub-plot 1 sample interval 2", \
            [1:12:1]  '+' u 1:1 pt "2" ti "sub-plot 2 sample interval 1", \
            [33:66:6] '+' u 1:1 pt "3" ti "sub-plot 3 sample interval 6"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Ok, this clarifies a lot. And if you know what to search for you will also find this statement in the manual... `help sampling 1D`. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Let me summarize my learnings, I'm a bit confused about ranges, samples and parametric.

What I wanted to achieve is the following:

3 curves with different ranges and different samples by one plot command. For example to illustrate:

- **Random**: 1000 random points in the range [0:2][0:2]
- **Circle**: Circle with radius 1 and 24 points in the range [-1:1][-1:1]
- **Line**:   Straight line with 3 samples in the range [-0.5:0.5][-0.5:0.5]

Learnings:

1. if `parametric` is off, it does not not allow (gives an error) to specify `[start:end:step]` in the first plot command, whereas it is tolerated in the second and third (sub)plot-command. Strange.
2. if `parametric` is on, the `step` in the first plot command will be ignored and number of samples will be defined by the previous `set samples`. Not so obvious.
3. if `parametric` is off, I cannot achieve the desired result.
4. I have to use `set parametric` *together* with `[start:end:step] '+' u ...`

Long story short. I can achieve the desired results when coding something like:

```
set parametric
set samples samples1   # because step1 will be ignored
plot [start1:end1:step1] '+' u (<whatever>):(<whatever>) ti "sub-plot 1", \
     [start2:end2:step2] '+' u (<whatever>):(<whatever>) ti "sub-plot 2", \
     [start3:end3:step3] '+' u (<whatever>):(<whatever>) ti "sub-plot 3"
```

The code and graph below show different options with/without `parametric` and different order of the 3 curves.
Only the bottom row in the graph below shows the desired results.

**Code:**

```
 ### curves with different ranges & samples within one plot command
reset session
set colorsequence classic

Random      = "[0:1:0.001]    '+' u (2*rand(0)):(2*rand(0)) w p pt 7 ps 0.5 not"
RandomFirst = "[0:1]          '+' u (2*rand(0)):(2*rand(0)) w p pt 7 ps 0.5 not"
Circle      = "[0:2*pi:pi/12] '+' u (cos($1)):(sin($1)) w lp pt 7 not"
CircleFirst = "[0:2*pi]       '+' u (cos($1)):(sin($1)) w lp pt 7 not"
Line        = "[-0.5:0.5:0.5] '+' u 1:1 w lp pt 7 lw 2 not"
LineFirst   = "[-0.5:0.5]     '+' u 1:1 w lp pt 7 lw 2 not"

set multiplot layout 4,3 columnsfirst

    set label 1 "random/circle/line" at screen 0.166,0.99 center
    unset parametric
        set title "parametric OFF"
        plot @RandomFirst, @Circle, @Line
    set parametric
        set title "parametric ON"
        plot @Random, @Circle, @Line
    unset parametric
    set samples 1000
        set title "parametric OFF"
        plot @RandomFirst, @Circle, @Line
    set parametric
        set title "parametric ON"
        plot @Random, @Circle, @Line

    set label 2 "line/random/circle" at screen 0.5,0.99 center
    unset parametric
        set title "parametric OFF"
        plot @LineFirst, @Random, @Circle
    set parametric
        set title "parametric ON"
        plot @Line, @Random, @Circle
    set samples 3
    unset parametric
        set title "parametric OFF"
        plot @LineFirst, @Random, @Circle
    set parametric
        set title "parametric ON"
        plot @Line, @Random, @Circle


    set label 3 "circle/line/random" at screen 0.833,0.99 center
    unset parametric
        set title "parametric OFF"
        plot @CircleFirst, @Line, @Random, 
    set parametric
        set title "parametric ON"
        plot @Circle, @Line, @Random, 
    set samples 24
    unset parametric
        set title "parametric OFF"
        plot @CircleFirst, @Line, @Random, 
    set parametric
        set title "parametric ON"
        plot @Circle, @Line, @Random, 

    unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]