# Gnuplot: How to restrict multiple parametric plots to different ranges?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot three parametric curves where each of them has a different range.
I checked the [demo script page](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/sampling.html) and the 9th plot demonstrates what I want to do. However, this does not work for my code:

```
set parametric
#set urange [0:2*pi]
#set vrange[0.3*pi:pi]
# Parametric functions for the sphere
set samples 1000
wplus = 20
wminus = 1
wz = 10
# 0 = one large circle
rhoplus0 = 0
rhominus0 = 10
rhoz0 = 0
fx0(u) = rhoplus0*cos(wplus*u) + rhominus0*cos(wminus*u)
fy0(u) = -rhoplus0*sin(wplus*u) - rhominus0*sin(wminus*u)
fz0(u)   = rhoz0*cos(wz*u)
# 1 = axial oscillation
rhoplus1 = 0
rhominus1 = 10
rhoz1 = 5
fx1(u) = rhoplus1*cos(wplus*u) + rhominus1*cos(wminus*u)
fy1(u) = -rhoplus1*sin(wplus*u) - rhominus1*sin(wminus*u)
fz1(u)   = rhoz1*cos(wz*u)
# 2 = many small circles
rhoplus2 = 2
rhominus2 = 10
rhoz2 = 0
fx2(u) = rhoplus2*cos(wplus*u) + rhominus2*cos(wminus*u)
fy2(u) = -rhoplus2*sin(wplus*u) - rhominus2*sin(wminus*u)
fz2(u)   = rhoz2*cos(wz*u)
splot [u=0:2*pi] fx0(u),fy0(u),fz0(u),\
      [u=pi:2*pi] fx1(u),fy1(u),fz1(u), \
      [u=0:pi] fx2(u),fy2(u),fz2(u)
```

The plot only ever takes the last range in u, in my case`[u=0:pi]`:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3dSU.png)

I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493814/gnuplot-how-to-set-multiple-ranges-in-parametric-plots), however, it did not solve my issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Both the demo plot and the previous answered question that you reference provide examples of plots similar to yours, together with some explanation.

The key point is to ***not*** use parametric mode. Instead revise your splot command to use either the 1-dimensional sampling 'pseudo-file' `+` or the 2-dimensional 'pseudo-file' `++`.  The conventional sampling variable is `t` in the 1D case, `u` and `v` in the 2D case.  Here is a trivial example:

```
# parametric mode
set parametric
set trange [0 : 2*pi]
splot fx(t), fy(t), fz(t)

# equivalent plot using pseudo-file '+'
unset parametric
set trange [0 : 2*pi]
splot '+' using (fx(t)) : (fy(t)) : (fz(t))
```

In both of the above plots, the number of points plotted is taken from the default sampling size (100), which can be changed using the `set sample` command.  The samples are drawn evenly to span `trange`.

There is an additional wrinkle to consider if instead of using a prior `set trange` command you move the sampling description into the plot command.  In this case the sampling specification `[t= <start> : <end> : <increment>]` is limited to integer values. You can think of `t` as being an index into an array of samples.  In your case the simplest way to do this is switch from radians to degrees.  `[t=0:360]` would generate 361 samples (rather than the 100 we got before). `[t=0:360:4]` would generate 91 samples, etc.

So your revised plot command is going to look something like this:

```
set angle degrees
splot sample [t=0:360:2]   using (fx0(t)) : (fy0(t)) : (fz0(t)),\
             [t=180:360:1] using (fx1(t)) : (fy1(t)) : (fz1(t)), \
             [t=0:180:1]   using (fx2(t)) : (fy2(t)) : (fz2(t))
```

This gives you 181 samples for each plot component even though they have different size ranges.  If you require a larger number of samples (your example used `set sample 1000`) you would have to further modify the command, e.g.:

```
sample [t=0:3600:20] using (fx0(t/10.)) : (fy0(t/10.)) : (fz0(t/10.))
```

That should get you started.  If you revise your code along those lines and it still does not work, please update the question to show the revised code and describe what isn't working.