# How to draw tangent line to a data point in gnuplot?

Tags: csv, plot, gnuplot

I am wondering how to draw a tangent line to a data point from csv data file in gnuplot.
Thanks for help

I tried some sort of fitting but it does not work.

Comment: What have you tried? What does "does not work" mean? On StackOverflow, please always show your own research effort and give enough information about your input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you specify your data point for the tangent? By x-value? Are there unique y-values for all x-values?
You give very little information and no example data, so I assume something.

Get the current and previous x-values into the variables `x1` and `x0`, respectively. If your x-value for the tangent `xt` is between `x0` and `x1` calculate the slope `m` and the y-axis-offset `c`.
Your tangent line then is `y = m*x + c`.

If you want to plot a tangent to a function you could use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58481857/7295599).

**Script:**

```
### plot a tangent to a dataset
reset session

# create some test data
$RawData <<EOD
 0   0
 1   1
 2   4
 3   2
 4   1
 5   2
EOD
set table $Data
    plot $RawData u 1:2 smooth mcsplines
unset table

xt = 2.1

getTangent(colX,colY) = (x0=x1, y0=y1, x1=column(colX), y1=column(colY), \
                    sgn(xt-x0)!=sgn(xt-x1) ? (m=(y1-y0)/(x1-x0), c=y0-x0*m) : 0)

plot x1=y1=NaN $Data u 1:(getTangent(1,2),$2) w l lc "red" ti "Data", \
        '+' u 1:(m*$1+c) w l lc "blue" ti sprintf("Tangent at x=%g",xt)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Here is a more general solution which also allows for

- vertical tangents
- tangents to curves with multiple y-values to one x-value

You specify a point `xt,yt` and the closest datapoint on the curve is taken for the tangent.

**Script:**

```
### plot a tangent to a dataset with multiple y-values to one x
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    set samples 300
    plot [t=0:5.5*pi] '+' u ($1*2*cos($1)):($1*2*sin($1)) w table
unset table

set size ratio -1
set key noautotitle

getTangent(colX,colY,xt,yt) = (x0=x1, x1=column(colX), y0=y1, y1=column(colY), \
         d=sqrt((x1-xt)**2+(y1-yt)**2), d<dmin || $0==0 ? \
         (dmin=d, xp=x1, yp=y1, at=atan2(y1-y0,x1-x0)) : 0, y1)

plot dmin=x1=y1=NaN $Data u 1:(getTangent(1,2,12,2.5)) w lp pt 7 ps 0.3 lc "web-green", \
     [-25:25] '+' u (xp+$1*cos(at)):(yp+$1*sin(at)) w l lc "red", \
     dmin=x1=y1=NaN $Data u 1:(getTangent(1,2,-13,10)) w lp pt 7 ps 0.3 lc "web-green", \
     [-25:25] '+' u (xp+$1*cos(at)):(yp+$1*sin(at)) w l lc "blue"

### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]